# Why does the lower body rotate in the opposite direction when the upper body is "thrown"?

Tags: angular-momentum, conservation-laws

[image: Physics of jumping on trampoline by "throwing" illustrated.]

From what I've read this is because angular momentum must be conserved, but I don't understand why it would go in the opposite direction. Is it because there has to be a net angular momentum of zero?

Comment: With no external torques the angular momentum has to be conserved. The trampoline provides the external torque to produce a net rotation.  https://www.wired.com/2016/08/physics-behind-every-olympic-gymnasts-twist/